# Vaadin: How to react to a tray notification click?

Tags: vaadin7

I'm using Tray Notifications to let the user know about some pending actions. It works fine but would love to be able to click on it and do what I need it to do like showing the correct screen, etc. Sadly I'm unable to find some click listener like other components.

Am I'm missing something?

Comment: Are you using Vaadin 7 or 8?

Comment: I'm using Vaadin 7

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that's not possible with the [default notification](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-notifications.html) in either Vaadin 7 or 8.

---

If you're using Vaadin 7, you can either fake it using a non-modal window (or something similar), or use the [fancy-layouts add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/fancylayouts) (also compatible with 8) that offers a `FancyNotifications` component ([online demo](http://app.siika.fi/FancyLayoutsDemo/) and [source](https://github.com/alump/FancyLayouts/blob/master/fancylayouts-demo/src/main/java/org/vaadin/alump/fancylayouts/demo/NotificationsDemo.java)). It's not exactly the same thing but it may provide what you need. Also be careful to select the v7 version and to add the suggested maven repo.

**Basic usage:**

```java
public class MyUi extends UI {
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        FancyNotifications fancyNotifications = new FancyNotifications();
        fancyNotifications.setPosition(FancyNotificationsState.Position.BOTTOM_RIGHT);

        Button button = new Button("Show notification", buttonClickEvent -> {
            FancyNotification fancyNotification = new FancyNotification(null, "Meh", "Click me to navigate to GITHUB");
            fancyNotification.getTitleLabel().setContentMode(ContentMode.HTML);
            fancyNotification.getDescriptionLabel().setContentMode(ContentMode.HTML);
            fancyNotification.addLayoutClickListener(notificationClickEvent -> Page.getCurrent().setLocation("https://github.com/alump/FancyLayouts"));
            fancyNotifications.showNotification(fancyNotification);
        });

        VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
        content.setSizeFull();
        setContent(content);

        content.addComponents(button, fancyNotifications);
        content.setComponentAlignment(button, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image: fancy notifications]

---

If you're using 8, there's the [notify add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/notify) ([online demo](http://app.siika.fi/NotifyDemo/) and [github page](https://github.com/alump/Notify)) which supports click-listeners. Please be aware that this add-on currently supports Vaadin 8 and works with browsers that support the Notification API:

> Development is mainly done on Chrome. Also Firefox is tested and mainly works as planned. Other browsers are still not tested. IE11 and Edge does not support Notification API as far as I know. Anyway add-on can use used only to show notifications on browsers that do support Notification APIs.

From the [github demo](https://github.com/alump/Notify/blob/master/notify-demo/src/main/java/org/vaadin/alump/notify/demo/DemoUI.java#L295):

```
private void showWithClickHandling() {
    Notify.show(new NotifyItem()
            .setTitle("Notification can be also clicked")
            .setBody("Click here to navigate to project's GitHub page")
            .setIcon(new ThemeResource("images/github.png"))
            .setClickListener(e -> {
                Page.getCurrent().setLocation(GITHUB_URL);
            }));
}
```

... which will look like:

[image: clickable-tray-notification]

Comment: I'm referring to the default Notification classes within Vaadin.

Comment: This looks like what I need, but I'm not ready to move to Vaadin 8. Transition is so painful as you need to basically re-write all the code as the API changed in most cases.

Comment: @javydreamercsw Updated answer with a possible solution for 7 as well. Not perfect but hopefully sufficient. Either way, as far as I know the default notifications don't have this functionality